# Data does not remain saved in sd card of emulator when I run application again but the data remains saved when I run it on phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I am making an application in which I download data from the internet and saved it on the sd card.
The second time the application runed, I checked wheather it is already downloaded or not. If it is present in sd card, I don't downloaded again. It is working fine on phone. But in emulator, the data is downloaded from internet each time I run the application?

Comment: create or edit the emulator with SD card size option..

Comment: I created the sd card and give size of 512Mib but data is lost each time when run application and its again downloaded from net.